# How to split comma separated string into 3 variables in Beanshell Preprocessor?

Tags: java, arrays, string, jmeter, beanshell

I have the following values in `user defined variables`, like

```
10001,1.2.840.13456.2.40.4.8323328.55551296.600114,D:\\Share\\DataSetCreation\\UPLOAD\\P7\\S1 (separated by comma)
```

[image: User Defined Variables]
In the `BeanShell Preprocessor`, I want to read these values and split into 3 variables based on the iteration.

For example for iteration1 for any user, I want upload1 and for iteration2 and I want upload2 data split into 3 variables.

How can I use `${__iterationNum}` in the below code to read the data from each user defined variables?

```
String data1 ="${upload2}";
String[] uploaddata = data1.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < uploaddata.length; i++)
{ log.info(uploaddata[i]); 
log.info("Value is: " + uploaddata[i]); }
```

Comment: Well, show us what you tried please. They won't code it for free. And add your language in the tags, otherwise it won't reach "relevant" people.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your current method is how you get variable:

```
String data1 =vars.get("upload2");
// ...
```

And to use an iteration with it:

```
// Choose one of 5 variables
String data1 = vars.get("upload" + (vars.getIteration() % 5));
// ...
```